# Set Flycheck enable for other mode

Tags: emacs, flycheck

Currently, my emacs's flycheck is enabled for js as default. I'm using global-flycheck-mode but not sure if I have set its value as a list. I wonder how to enable flycheck for other modes like json-mode, web-mode, c++mode. Here is my settings for flycheck.

```
;; ===================flycheck settings start====================
;; use web-mode for .jsx files
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jsx$" . web-mode))

;; http://www.flycheck.org/manual/latest/index.html
(require 'flycheck)

;; turn on flychecking globally
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)

;; disable jshint since we prefer eslint checking
(setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers
              (append flycheck-disabled-checkers
                      '(javascript-jshint)))

;; use eslint with web-mode for jsx files
(flycheck-add-mode 'javascript-eslint 'web-mode)

;; customize flycheck temp file prefix
(setq-default flycheck-temp-prefix ".flycheck")

;; disable json-jsonlist checking for json files
(setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers
              (append flycheck-disabled-checkers
                      '(json-jsonlist)))

;; https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell
;; only need exec-path-from-shell on OSX
;; this hopefully sets up path and other vars better
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))

;; for better jsx syntax-highlighting in web-mode
;; - courtesy of Patrick @halbtuerke
(defadvice web-mode-highlight-part (around tweak-jsx activate)
  (if (equal web-mode-content-type "jsx")
      (let ((web-mode-enable-part-face nil))
        ad-do-it)
    ad-do-it))

;; c++
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook (lambda () (setq flycheck-gcc-language-standard "c++11")))
;; ===================flycheck settings end======================
```

Answer (score 1):

Im currently using this one. Works fine.

```
;; Enable for other modes
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)
(add-hook 'json-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)
```

But I still don't understand why it only enables for js2-mode before.